# Adding a small UIView to an SKScene

Tags: uitableview, swift, sprite-kit

I have a Swift + SpriteKit game in development, in which I would like to insert a small UITableViewController into a small (100 x 200) UIView, and then add that view to my SKScene. I am using this code:

```
class BugsScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("bugs", forKey: "lastSceneViewed")

        let bugsTableView: BugsTVC = BugsTVC()
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: bugsTableView)

        let smallerRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200)
        let smallerView = UIView(frame: smallerRect)
        smallerView.addSubview(nav.view)
        self.view.addSubview(smallerView)
    }
}
```

However, in landscape mode (my app only supports landscape left and landscape right, NO portrait), the tableview occupies the entire height of the landscape mode, and has the width of an iPad in portrait.

How do I add a small UIView to a bigger scene in swift/spritekit?

Comment: change the view's frame property

Comment: So in the code above, I set the frame of the UIView when I initialize it. Do you mean something different from this?  Setting the frame of the smaller view separately from the init doesn't seem to have an affect.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D  Your comment was dead-on.  My problem was that I was failing to set the frame of the nav controller, which the tableview sits in.  Turn this into an answer and I'll select it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LearnCocos2D definitely deserves credit for this, so if he ever posts an answer I will accept it.  Essentially, I was failing to set the frame for the navigation controller's view.  Here is my method for adding the smaller view to the scene:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

        self.name = "Bugs Scene"
        backgroundColor = bugsColor

        let smallerRect = CGRectMake(400, 24, 600, 720)
        let navRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 720)
        let bugsTableView: BugsTVC = BugsTVC()
        nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: bugsTableView)
        nav.view.frame = navRect
        smallerView = UIView(frame: smallerRect)
        smallerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        bugsTableView.view.frame = smallerRect
        smallerView.frame = smallerRect
        smallerView.addSubview(nav.view)
        self.view.addSubview(smallerView)


    }
```

It could probably be refined some but this is working for me.  Now if I can only figure out how to remove the view when I transition to another scene!

Comment: Could you please show me your table class, because I followed this method but the table doesn't appear, the UIView and the Nav shows.

Comment: Hi Abdou023.  Since this question was asked I ended up re-writing everything in SpriteKit, and no longer use any UIKit elements in my SpriteKit apps.  The two just do not play nicely together.

Comment: So, you made an alternative to UITableView using the SpriteKit framework ?

Comment: I wish!  I don't remember how I reworked the app I was working on to not use UITableView, but that was at least the decision I made.  I have not worked on that app for a long time.  However, SpriteKit would definitely benefit from some equivalents of some of the more useful UIKit elements.  UIScrollView, anyone?  Multi-line labels?  There are so many things missing from SpriteKit.

Comment: To remove the view from the scene, before you change scenes add the line `view.removeFromSuperview()`